# How do you combine different SQL queries into a single dataframe (Python)?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I have two separate python files which read and store the sql query into a dataframe.

```
 1. MySQL with SSH
 2. SQL Server
```

Is there a way to put both those results into a single dataframe ? Please see below my two code examples.

I am extremely new to python and I'm sure there might be a very simple solution to this.

SQL Server py script:

```
    import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

server = '******.database.windows.net' 
database = '******' 
# username = '******' 
# password = '******'
sqlconn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = sqlconn.cursor()
current_date = pd.datetime.now()

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT TOP 5 * FROM db',sqlconn)
sql_query.head()
sql_query.info

print(sql_query)
print(type(sql_query))


pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

mySQL Script:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql as db
import sshtunnel as ssh
import urllib.request as urllib2
import json
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import sys



#def query(q):
 # SSH Variables
host = '*.*.*.*'
hostname = '******'
ssh_username = '*****'
ssh_pw = '******'
 # database variables
dbuser = '*****'
dbpw = '******'
schema = '******'
 
def query(q):
    with ssh.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (host,22),
        ssh_username=ssh_username,
        ssh_password=ssh_pw,
        remote_bind_address=(hostname,3306),
        set_keepalive=30
        ) as tunnel:
        conn = db.connect(
            host='localhost',       
            user=dbuser,
            passwd=dbpw,
            port=tunnel.local_bind_port
            )
        print(query)
        data = pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)
        conn.close()
    return data
    
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)


 #return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)
df = query(""" SELECT * FROM db """)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  
    print(df)
```

Comment: You might want to link the servers together and run a single query in one of the databases -- a query that can access tables in the other database.

Comment: It is not possible to link the servers together. They are in completely separate environments. To be honest that is why I am trying python to link the two tables and push the final table into SQL Server.

Comment: . . As far as I know, a linked server in SQL Server only needs to be accessible on the internet.  You might want to learn about linked servers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), because it might be a better long term solution.